# Bind a javascript value in detailsview

Tags: jquery, asp.net, detailsview

I am new to ASP.NET. I was trying to get a value of jQuery variable and use it in details view. These are the values in jQuery

```
   $("#beginDate").html(data[i].BeginDate);
   $("#eventTypeID").html(data[i].EVENT_TYPE_ID);
   $("#endDate").html(data[i].EndDate);
   $("#beginlatlong").html(data[i].BeginLATLONG);
   $("#endlatlong").html(data[i].EndLATLONG);
```

So, I was trying to do this inside detailsview:

```
<asp:DetailsView ID="de" runat="server" >
<Fields>
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Duplicate">
<ItemTemplate>
<strong>Begin Date:</strong>
<asp:Label runat="server" ID="beginDate" Text='<%# Eval("beginDate") %>'></asp:Label>
</ItemTemplate>

</asp:TemplateField>
</Fields>
</asp:DetailsView>
```

But the detailsview is not showing up on the browser. Can u let me know the mistake i've been doing?

Comment: Text='<%# Eval("beginDate") %>' and $("#beginDate").html(data[i].BeginDate); ? use one way/value.

Comment: Do you mean the entire DetailsView is not showing, or is just the value not visible? Also keep in mind that the ID you're using in jQuery is most likely wrong. You'd need to use $("#<%= beginDate.ClientID %>") or set CLientIDMode=Static on the beginDate label.

Comment: @matk:I can't see the details view itself.... Moreover, feel that I made some mistake in getting the value in detailsview

Comment: @MLS Can u just explain it more clearly..

Comment: If the DetailsView is not visible, maybe you didn't bind it to any data? If the control is not databound then of course there is nothing to display. try de.DataSource = <your data>; de.DataBind();

Comment: @matk: I have a doubt here. Since I need to bound the values I wrote in jQuery. I'm not sure how to set datasource because datasource usually is done by retrieving values from database. So, can u let me know how I can do this?

Comment: it should work, can u debug it using console.debug?

Comment: There are many resources online, see for example here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb288033.aspx.

Comment: framework should support javascript debugging. just make sure if ur label is getting value?

Comment: @MLS: It is getting a value. I used <span id="beginDate"> to check and its returning a value

Comment: @user838359: I thought you said the DetailsView itself is not visible? How then can the label have a value?

Answer (score 0):

`<asp:Label runat="server" ID="beginDate"` will render different id, use that rendered id in ur jquery statement `$("#beginDate").html(data[i].BeginDate);`